# Loops with arrays in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, loops, basic

I'm not a programmer. 15 years in IT but I don't write code.  Taking this class in Visual Basic to expand my horizons and while I'm doing ok, sometimes I get stumped.  We are working on arrays and the assignment is an employee directory.  I have my arrays declared for names, id's, phone numbers and salaries but I am now trying to code the search button to search by these fields and am lost.  Here's what the assignment calls for.  The blanks are what I'm having trouble with:

[Loop code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOUtx.jpg)

Here's what I have so far:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim input As String = txtEmployee.Text

    If input = "" Then
        lblStatus.Text = "No search name entered"
        Return
    End If

    Dim found As Boolean = False

    For i As Integer = 0 To employees AND HERE'S WHERE I'M STUCK

End Sub
```

I know it's looking for those values to be true, but not sure how to code it. I know this may be somewhat simple for a lot, but I really struggle with this stuff.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `For i as Integer = 0 to employees.Count -1 Step 1`

Comment: Thank you. I think I figured the rest of it out. There's another button I may have some trouble with but I had to walk away from it for a while.

Comment: Try learning Python first. Visual Basic is quite a clumsy language, Python is simple, easy-to-use, powerful, and used in the real world.